# Is there a way to save my Python OLS regression as csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, save, regression

I am kinda new to python so i guess this could be an easy task.
I am running an ols regression and my output is already fine. Now I just want to save the output from
`print(fit.summary())`as csv.

Here is my whole code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\kilia\Desktop\BA\data\F-F_Research_Data_Factors.CSV")

X = df[['Mkt-RF', 'SMB', 'HML']].values
X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = df[['Pf_excess_return']].values

model = sm.OLS(y,X)
fit = model.fit()
print(fit.summary())
```

I already tried `fit.to_csv (r'C:\Users\kilia\Desktop\BA\data', index = False, header=True)`
But doesnt seem to work.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this output is what you exactly want, but you can use `as_csv` method. Note that `as_csv` only converts result to string representing content of csv file, but does not save it to file, thats why I am using `open` (which opens file) and `write` (which writes to that file)

```
>>> out = fit.summary()
>>> with open('fname.csv','w') as f:
...     f.write(out.as_csv())
... 
1280
>>>
```

final csv file:
[image: final csv output]